# C++ design help for templated virtual function

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I'm trying to implement a number of classes based on a a common class that abstracts a thread-pool using boost.threadpool. I've got something that works (in Xcode on osx 10.7.2)  but I'm really not sure its good design or if its even safe (largely because of what I've read on-line about the use of virtual member functions with templates). I'm looking for some style advice on the best way to implement something like this. I'm learning as I go along here so I know a lot of this will be 'bad form'...

I have a base class called 'workqueue' like this:

```
template <typename T> 
class Workqueue{

    private:
        pool            *pThreadPool;

    public:
        Workqueue       (int);        
        void Start      (T);        
        void Schedule   (T);
        virtual bool Process(T) {return true;}
};

template <typename T> Workqueue<T>::Workqueue(int thread_count){
    pThreadPool = new pool(thread_count);
}

template <typename T> void Workqueue<T>::Start(T data){
    pThreadPool->schedule(boost::bind(&Workqueue::Process,this, data));  
    pThreadPool->wait();
}

template <typename T> void Workqueue<T>::Schedule(T data){
    pThreadPool->schedule(boost::bind(&Workqueue::Process,this, data));    
}
```

I then define a new service based on this class like this:

```
struct Service1Data{
    string item_data;
};

class MyService : public Workqueue<Service1Data> {    
public:
    MyService       (int);
    bool Process    (Service1Data);        
};

MyService::MyService(int workers) : Workqueue<Service1Data>(workers) {}

bool MyService::Process(Service1Data service_data){
    cout << "in process (" << service_data.item_data << ")" << endl;     
    return true;
}
```

(I've removed as much of the code to keep it simple so as shown would run forever as it continually submits new work). I use the service like this:

```
    MyService *service1 = new MyService(5);

    Service1Data x;
    x.item_data = "testing";
    service1->Start(x);

    // will wait until no more work.
    delete service1;
```

so my specific questions:

firstly (and please be gentle...) is this bad form and is there a much better way to do this? (and why?)

secondly - is this even safe given the virtual/template issues? I read somewhere that it should be safe if the class itself is templated and I think I understand the basic vtable issues - but really not sure of the specifics.

thirdly - the base workqueue class needs to have the member definitions in the 'h' file with the class definition for it to link. Not sure why that would be - I imagine it's a linker issue to do with the virtual/template issues and so makes me nervous.

all help gratefully received..

Chris

Comment: "read somewhere that it should be safe if the class itself is templated" - Correct, it's only the `template<class T> virtual void f(T);` thing that just doesn't work out. If you have a templated class, the argument type of the function is already determined and only a single entry in the vtable is needed.

Comment: thanks - presumably because the class template will be resolved at compile time? Is that correct?

Comment: *Any* template will be resolved at compile time - that's their nature. You only get a problem with real virtual function templates, because a different vtable entry would be needed for every argument type that the function might get called with, which is impossible.

Comment: There is a bunch of other issues: `Workqueue` needs a virtual destructor, `pool` is never deleted (I'd recommend a `unique_ptr`) and I don't see why it is allocated on the free-store anyway.

Comment: all good points - i'll move the pool off the free-store and add a virtual destructor thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you shouldn't mix *processing of data* with *processing of queue*.

I mean, you shouldn't have `Process` method in your `Workqueue`. `Data` may process itself, or your queue can get processing function as (*template*?) parameter.

Then you get rid of all your problems with virtual function. `YourService` class then should agregate `Workqueue` and may provide process function.

Also, I doubt if you really need `Workqueue`. You can just use `pThreadPool` in `YourService`.

If you need a common interface for services, you should specify it explicitly & separately. Your inheritance chain looks unclear. inheritance means *is*. Why `YourService` *is* `Workqueue`. *I do not believe!* I think `YourService` can *use* any sort of queue. But *usage* is aggregation.

EDIT:
Code will look like this:

```
template<typename Processor>
class WorkQueue
{
public:
    WorkQueue(int count, Processor& processor):_processor(processor),_pool(count) {}

    template <typename Data>
    void schedule(const Data& data)
    {
        _pool->schedule(std::bind(&Processor::process,_processor, data));
    }

    template <typename Data>
    void run(const Data& data)
    {
        schedule(data);
        _pool->wait();
    }

private:
    Processor& _processor;
    pool _pool;
};

class Service
{
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
    virtual ~Service() {}
};

struct ServiceParams
{
    int param;
};

class MyService: public Service
{

    friend class WorkQueue<MyService>;
public:
    MyService(const ServiceParams& params): _params(params), _queue(1, *this) {}
    void run() { return _queue.run(_params); }
private:
    ServiceParams _params;
    WorkQueue<MyService> _queue;

    void process(const ServiceParams& params) {std::cout <<"hello, world\n";}
};
```

EDIT: I originally considered usage as:

```
ServiceData data;
Service* service = new MyService(data);
service->run();
delete service;
```

Comment: sounds interesting - the point of not using thread pool in my service was so that I could abstract it away and make writing multiple services very easy. My idea was to remove any notion of the queue from the service - it's just a case of writing the process (which may submit more service-specific work. Can you give me an idea of how it would be structured using aggregation?

Comment: Do you need start _same_ service more than once with different parameters? (It's important for design)

Comment: thanks for the code example - really helps and looks good. One think i'm a bit confused about - to use it it seems I need to do:  ServiceParams x; MyService y(x); WorkQueue<MyService> z(5,y); z.run(x);   If i've got that right (it compiles like that anyway) I have to instantiate MyService with the data, but then also pass the data to run on MyService. Can I just drop the data from the constructor of the MyService?

Comment: I added usage example to post. See my edit. if you want to use it as you showed (with queue created separately), you'd better use @havexz design.

Comment: thats great - i misunderstood the implied usage. Simply adding the num_threads param to the constructor of MyService means I can create the service with the data and the number of threads to process it - and importantly in this design it still provides access to the queue inside my service so my process can itself submit further work to be processed. Many thanks..

Comment: one further question if I may - is there any reason not to move the friend relationship and the reference to the queue that's currently in the MyService down to the base service class? Just thinking that as it is, anyone writing a new service will be required to know that they need to set up that relationship and get the workQueue from the 'this' pointer in the constructor?

Comment: You cannot do this currently. This is because your base class `Service` do not have `process` method and you cannot add it, because process method take `ServiceParams`, but your base class knows nothing about `ServiceParams`. Of cause you can change `process` signature to `void process()` and make it virtual... but there is a _verity_ of things you can do and I cannot show you _all_ possible design variants.

Answer (score 0):

Little things I can obviously point out:

- overuse of new and delete when you could create automatic objects.

For example, if your work-queue and the pool have the same lifetime then:

```
template <typename T>  class Workqueue
{      
    private:
      pool            threadPool;  
 // // etc
};

template< typename T >
Workqueue::Workqueue( int numThreads ) : threadPool( numThreads )
{
}
```

Your base class needs a virtual destructor, and as it stands Start could call Schedule rather than implement the same line of code (with the boost::bind) twice. Ideally the constructor that takes an int member only will be declared explicit.

You probably need logic to wait for threads to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good design should isolate the queuing and work/task separately. In your design, both are tightly coupled. This design is good if you want to create separate pool for every type of work/task.

Another approach is to create a separate `Work` class containing the `process` function. Then your `MyService` will extend `Work`. And `WorkQueue` class will accept `Work` and by that means any derived class too. This approach is more generic in nature. So same worker queue can accept different type of work/task. Below code illustration will clear more.

Just to add this approach can also be used if you want to have different pool for different type of data. It is more flexible in nature.

```
template <typename T> 
class Work{
    T data; // contains the actual data to work on
    public:
        Work(T data) : data(data) {} // constructor to init data
        virtual bool Process(T) {return false;} // returns false to tell process failed
        T getData() { return data; } // get the data
};

class MyWork : public Work<Service1Data> {    
public:
    MyService (Service1Data data) : 
      Work(data) {}
    bool Process (Service1Data); // Implement your work specific process func
};

bool MyWork::Process(Service1Data service_data){
    cout << "in process (" << service_data.item_data << ")" << endl;     
    return true;
}

class Workqueue{

    private:
        pool            *pThreadPool;

    public:
        Workqueue       (int);        
        void Start      (Work);        
        void Schedule   (Work);
};

Workqueue::Workqueue(int thread_count){
    pThreadPool = new pool(thread_count);
}

void Workqueue::Start(Work workToDo){
    pThreadPool->schedule(boost::bind(&Work::Process,this, workToDo.getData()));  
    pThreadPool->wait();
}

void Workqueue::Schedule(Work data){
    pThreadPool->schedule(boost::bind(&Work::Process,this, workToDo.getData()));    
}
```

**Usage**

```
Service1Data x;
x.item_data = "testing";
MyWork myWork(x);


Workqueue wq = new Workqueue(5);
wq->Start(myWork);

// will wait until no more work.
delete service1;
```

Now to achieve different pools for different type of work/task, create two `Workqueue` with different pool size and then give one only one type of work and other another type of work.

NOTE: Above code might contain syntax errors, it just there to convey the design. Treat it as pseudo code.

Comment: well i was thinking of having a separate queue for each service - then I can balance the resource by, say, giving one thread to serviceA and five threads to service B. However - your suggestion makes sense and would actually add flexibility as I can have a many-to-many relationship between queues and work. Thanks

Comment: BTW you can achieve that too (wat u saying), by creating two `Workqueue` with different pool size and then give one only one type of work and other another type of work. There other ways too to implement it but above will get you started.